# How do i convert .txt file to .csv file in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to copy the contents of `test.txt` (`FILE_MASTER`) to `test.csv` in shell script, what command should I use?

```
cp $FILE_MASTER test.csv
```

The contents of text.txt are as below (comma separated)

```
3058819,AA TIRES,,,2934 AJ
```

Comment: `cp file.txt file.csv`

Comment: It is not clear what your question is. If you only want to copy a file you already wrote the command in your question. Copying a file does not depend on its contents. In the title you wrote "convert .txt to .csv". If you want to **convert** the contents instead of copying it unchanged, please describe how exactly the data should be converted.

Answer (score 0):

The file contents already are *.csv*, (*i.e.* [***C**omma **S**eperated **V**alues*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)), so all that needs be done is to `cp` or `mv` the file to whatever name seems fitting:

```
cp "${FILE_MASTER}" test.csv
```